# "A4J is not defined" error from richfaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

We have an application using MyFaces 1.2 with richfaces 3.3.3 running on WebSphere Application Server v7 and have encountered an issue using a4j component in richfaces.

The ajax request does not appear to be submitting and we are seeing the following js error in firebug:

"ReferenceError: A4J is not defined"

It appears to be attempting to load the following resource -  /a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript.xhtml, however it is returning 0 byte file.
This issue is intermittent and is resolved by restarting the web/application server.

We have recently migrated web server from SunOne to Apache, could this be related?
Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance